# Backbone.js get part of collection

Tags: backbone.js

I want to get a part of a list/collection from the server, something like this:

```
// Model
FileItem = Backbone.Model.extend({});

// Collection
FileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: FileItem,
  url: function() {
    return '/me/file_list/' + this.id;
  }
});
```

but this does not work. It seems that I cannot have dynamic urls in collection?

Comment: @MinMingLo Are you trying to fetch a model? because using ID inside `collection.url` does not make any sense

Comment: Agree with @Deeptechtons. This is how backbone would fetch the model not the collection. For a list of collections, fetch() would make a request to '/me/file_list/' and to fetch a single modle, fetch would make a request to '/me/file_list/{Id of model}'.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Backbone.Paginator](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator) -- `Backbone.Paginator.requestPager` may be exactly what you're looking for here. There's a good [example of it in use](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone.paginator/examples/netflix-request-paging/index.html), including a `PaginatedCollection` base class to use for your collections.